# Saving and loading div locations - Zoom and save alters div location on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

So I have a bunch of divs that are absolute to an overlay. The user creates a square div by dragging on the overlay. If you were to create a div and then zoom in and out, the div stays positioned in the same spot since it is absolute to the overlay as mentioned before.

However here's where the problem is. You are able to save the div location (top, left, height, width) to a .json and load the .json to show all of your previously saved divs. This works fine.... if you save and load on the same browser zoom percentage.

If you were to draw divs on 150% zoom, for example, and try to load the div's position on 100% zoom, the position is altered (as to make up for the zoom I presume).

I tried forcing the window zoom to 100% on save, but that didn't work, and I am kind of stuck now. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: saving percentage values?

Comment: @Alex Yes! This did it! So simple and obvious I don't know how I didn't think of it. Had to restructure a good bit of my code, but I was able to get it working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Following Alex's advice to use percentages, I was able to come up with a solution that works perfectly.

In the method that sets the top and left of the div - I changed that from pixels relative to the parent to percentage relative to the parent.

So this

```
{
   width = endX - startX;
   left = startX;

   height = endY - startY;
   top = startY;
}
```

Became this

```
{
    width = endX - startX;
    var percentageLeft = startX / parent.offsetWidth * 100;
    left = percentageLeft;

    height = endY - startY;
    var percentageTop = startY / parent.offsetHeight * 100;
    top = percentageTop;
}
```

and then by changing the saving/loading to look for percentages instead of pixels, I was able to make this work!